# How to utilize the @ResponseStatus annotation when handling the ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I have the following service class:

```
@Service
public class CitiesServiceImpl implements CitiesService {
  @Autowired
  private CitiesRepository citiesRepository;
  @Override
  public City getCityById(Integer cityId) {
    return citiesRepository.findById(cityId)
            .orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new);
  }
}
```

and it is used in my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cities")
public class CitiesController {
  @Autowired
  private CitiesService citiesService;

  @GetMapping("/{cityId}")
  public City readCity(@PathVariable Integer cityId) {
    return citiesService.getCityById(cityId);
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
  String handleResourceNotFound(Exception e) {
    return e.getMessage();
  }
}
```

So when the `readCity` is called with a nonexistent `cityID`, the [`ResourceNotFoundException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/ResourceNotFoundException.html) will be thrown and then handled by the `handleResourceNotFound` exception handler.

However, **when the `ResouceNotFoundException` is handled, the status code in the response is still 202, i.e. OK. Seems that `@ResponseStatus` annotation in the `ResourceNotFoundException` is not utilized at run time. This can be fixed by adding the @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) to the method `handleResourceNotFound`, but such code is duplicate as the `@ResponseStatus` annotation is already in the `ResourceNotFoundException`.**

**Question: How to utilize the `ResponseStatus` annotation of the `ResourceNotFoundException` instead of adding duplicate code?**

Comment: Just remove that useless `handleResourceNotFound` method or return required code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove that `handleResourceNotFound` and let framework handle that for you, or return proper `Response` from `handleResourceNotFound` method.

By declaring such handler you are saying that you will handle such case, thus framework is backing off.

Comment: Thanks a lot! seems that the `ResourceNotFoundException` is handled by the Spring framework itself? and how?

Comment: It just catches that, anayzes annotations you have mentioned and generates proper response.